# Facing issue while using exchangelib to expand DL

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, configuration, exchangewebservices, exchangelib

I have a webapp built using flask.

Now, I have a requirement which needs me to expand a distribution list. I came across exchangelib library and tried using it.

I'm able to configure without any issue.
I'm using OAuth2.
I also have an app registered on Azure.

The exchangelib configuration is :

```
from exchangelib import OAuth2Credentials,Version,Build,Configuration,Account,Credentials,IMPERSONATION,OAUTH2
from exchangelib.version import EXCHANGE_O365

username = '<primary_smtp_email_id>' 
tenant_id = app.config['APP_TENANT_ID']
client_id = app.config['APP_CLIENT_ID']
secret_value = app.config['APP_CLIENT_SECRET']
version=Version(build=EXCHANGE_O365)
credentials = OAuth2Credentials(client_id=client_id, client_secret=secret_value, tenant_id=tenant_id)

config = Configuration(service_endpoint = 'https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx',
                        credentials=credentials,
                        auth_type=OAUTH2 , 
                        version=version)
account = Account(username, credentials=credentials, autodiscover=False, config=config, access_type=IMPERSONATION)
```

And the code to expand a DL :

```
def print_expanded_dl(dl):
    for mailbox in account.protocol.expand_dl(dl):
        print(mailbox.email_address)
```

But, I'm getting an error when I call the print_expanded_dl function.
The error that i am encountering is :

```
exchangelib.errors.ErrorInvalidExchangeImpersonationHeaderData: ExchangeImpersonation SOAP header must be present for this type of OAuth token.
```

Kindly help since I searched for similar cases and found that the access_type in configuration needs to be set to IMPERSONATION. I have already done it.
Also, The app on Azure has the following permissions :

[image]

Also, If there is any other way to expand a distribution list using some other library, Feel free to suggest the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also set the `identity` attribute on your `Credentials` instance, as described in https://ecederstrand.github.io/exchangelib/#oauth-authentication